# Login into Debug UART via ADB shell

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am using Linux in my custom embedded board (it is basically androidised Linux, where I can access adb shell but the JVM is removed).

I want to login into the debug UART port through the adb shell.
I did "echo root > /dev/ttyHSL0" on the corresponding tty port (for debug UART) present in the dev directory but was not able to login into the debug UART.

Is there a way to do this ?

If not, how can I remove the login feature from debug UART ?

Comment: Do you have GPIO on the board?

Comment: Yes. I have several usable GPIO's on my board.